# Datatype mismatch when trying to insert data into SQLite Database

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am trying to insert a record into a table in C#, but when I get to the line of code to execute the query to insert the record into the table, it just comes up with this error:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException' occurred in System.Data.SQLite.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: datatype mismatch

The code that I have to insert the data into the database is as follows:

```
string stmt = string.Format("INSERT INTO quotes (id, user, quote, date) VALUES ('', '{0}', '{1}', '{2}')", person, quote, date);

SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(stmt, connection);

int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

`person`, `quote` and `date` are all strings and the structure of the database is as follows:

`id = INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`, `user = STRING(255)`, `quote = STRING(255)` and `date = STRING(255)`

Comment: It looks like you're trying to insert a string (the first element in the values clause) into an integer (id).

Comment: I do not know about missmatch problem but you can write query like that too string stmt = string.Format("INSERT INTO quotes (user, quote, date) VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}')", person, quote, date); if id is autoincremented.

Comment: Start by using SQL PArameters.  If the text includes something like `O'Toole` it will crash; they will also assure the right type is passed

Comment: Why are you inserting an empty string in the ID ?

Comment: Look at this answer on how to do your task http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12785780/sqlite-insert-into-identity-column

Comment: I normally do that for PHP, so I guess it was just a habit @user3185569

Comment: @John Just don't specify the id column if it is auto generated column (Which seems to be from your definition) .. Like this: `INSERT INTO quotes (user, quote, date)`

Comment: Downvoter care to comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If id is autoincremented, you can insert data with this query

```
stmt = string.Format("INSERT INTO quotes (user, quote, date) VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}')", person, quote, date);
```

Comment: I will as soon as it lets me